# Ubuntu VM - Running Powershell script - takes snapshot - connects to Jenkins, but reverting to snapshot breaks script

Tags: powershell, ubuntu, jenkins, vsphere, powercli

I have an Ubuntu 22 VM running a powershell / powerCLI script when it boots.

```
New-Snapshot -VM $myName -Name "snapshot" -memory -RunAsync

#Wait for snapshot to complete
Sleep 60

#Connects to Jenkins using Java Swarm
```

The first run through works, it takes the snapshot and connects to Jenkins.

When I revert the VM to the snapshot, it's supposed to wait the 60 seconds then reconnect to Jenkins. But suddenly this stopped working.

It was working on Ubuntu 18, but stopped working after updating to Ubuntu 22. I didn't change anything else on the VM. It's running the latest Powershell and PowerCLI.

Not sure what else to try at the moment. Any help is appreciated.

Edit : Just tested this on older Ubuntu 18 VMs and having the same problem